# ¿Cómo descargar un pdf que tengo en mi servidor web con asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, descarga

Lo que necesito es bastante simple.

Tengo una App de Android donde el usuario marca un check list de las acciones que debe realizar, se guardan en una base de datos y se genera un PDF y lo guarda en un servidor web. Lo que yo estoy haciendo es mediante asp.net una página donde se pueda consultar el check list que hizo el usuario y descargar el PDF que se generó.
El problema lo estoy teniendo al querer descargar el PDF, ya que no encuentro un ejemplo práctico que me realice la descarga.

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

```
private void Descarga(string archivo)
{
    using (System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        wc.DownloadFile(archivo, "C:/Pruebas/CheckList.pdf");
    }
}
```

En el primer parámetro  del `DownloadFile` es el directorio del archivo que voy a descargar (que lo obtengo mediante `string archivo = Server.MapPath("~/Files_Site/Truck/CheckList.pdf");`) y el segundo parámetro es el destino de dónde se va a descargar.

Esto funciona perfecto, pero yo quiero que la descarga se haga mediante el navegador (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.) y no tener que indicar dónde se va a descargar, porque no tengo manera de saber cuál es la carpeta de descargas del usuario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta forma pude lograr la descarga.

```
private void Descarga(string archivo)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Nombre.pdf");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(archivo));
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```